# How to display image in html page of angular

Tags: angular

I am using Angular CLI 8.1.0 and i am new into Angular.
I am not able to display the image in my html page. My path is correct but still not getting the image.
I am getting error:

```
> unsafe:C:/nginx/www/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/Pictures/UserApp/Home/Brands/burgerking.png:1
> GET
> unsafe:C:/nginx/www/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/Pictures/UserApp/Home/Brands/burgerking.png
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

> approval.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.col=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('col');
    this.id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.rid=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('rid');

    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((queryParams:Params)=>{
      let col=this.col;
      let id=this.id;   
      let rid=this.rid;

      this.apiService.getVendorById(col,id,rid)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.result = data[0]; 
        this.getpath=this.result.strOutletUri;  
        this.finalpath="C:/nginx/www"+this.getpath; 

      });
    });
  }
```

> approval.component.html

```
<img src="{{finalpath}}"/><br>
```

> my REST API:

```
[
    {
        "strBusinessName": "Happy Junctions",
        "strBusinessDescription": "Restaurant ",
        "strOutletUri": "/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/Pictures/UserApp/Home/Brands/burgerking.png"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` property of `img` tag requires a [valid non-empty URL](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#valid-non-empty-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces). If you need to show local images from the server, try embedding them using [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). Although I am not sure if an absolute path will work in Angular.

Component

```js
this.finalpath = "url(C:/nginx/www" + this.getpath + ")";
```

Template

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': finalpath ? finalpath : 'none'}"></div>
```

**Update**

Angular does not have access to local file system. The images should either come from `src/assets/` folder or it should be sent as an encoded base64 of the image from the server. It can then be decoded in the Angular.

Comment: I've updated the `this.finalpath` definition. Do you get the same result with it updated too?

Comment: That's what I thought. Could you please post the exact error?

Comment: That is what I thought. Angular does not have access to local file system. The images should either come from `src/assets/` folder or you need to send the encoded base64 of the image from the server. It can then be decoded in the Angular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210159/discussion-between-ashish-mishra-and-michael-d).